# Examine convergence of improper integral

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

How do i test out convergence of improper integral

Given integral is $$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^m\cos(ax)}{(1+x^n)}dx$$

Answer is the given improper integral is convergent if $-1 < m < n $. I am thinking of applying p test, but how do i deal with $\cos(ax)$ term in numerator?

Thanks

Comment: Hint: at $x=0$ $\cos(ax)\sim 1$, and you may use p-test. At $x=\infty$ use Dirichlet

Comment: @MichaelGaluza i didn't study Dirichlet test yet, will absolute convergence work here(i thought it might get me rid of cosine).

Answer (score 1):

Some hints: The integral may not converge absolutely; the problem is at $\infty.$ Let $m=1,n=2$ to see this. You don't need to know Dirichlet to decide whether the integral is convergent. Try integrating by parts: Integrate $\cos (ax),$ differentiate $x^m/(1+x^n).$